# Weakly convex functions in the sense of support functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $I\subset\mathbb{R}$ be an interval, $f:I\to\mathbb{R}$ a continuous function.

- $f$ is called *convex* if for any $x,y\in I$, $t\in[0,1]$, we have $$f((1-t)x+ty)\leq (1-t)f(x)+tf(y).$$
- $f$ is called *weakly convex in the distribution sense* if $f''\geq0$ as a distribution.
- $f$ is called *weakly convex in the support sense* if for any $p\in I$, $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ in $I$ and a $C^2$ function $f_\varepsilon:U\to\mathbb{R}$ such that (1) $f_\varepsilon''(p)\geq-\varepsilon$; (2) $f\geq f_\varepsilon$ on $U$, with equality at $p$.

How are these notions related? Of course all three are equivalent when $f$ is $C^2$. But otherwise I'm unable to prove or disprove the implications. In particular, I need the fact convexity is equivalent to weak convexity in the sense of support functions (which I can't say for sure is correct).

Edit:

It is Exercise 7.5.3 in Peter Petersen's *Riemannian Geometry* to prove that being weakly convex in the support sense is equivalent to being convex. I especially need this result because this idea of using support functions has been used repeatedly later in the book.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Never heard of either of those definitions for weakly convex before, but why would one bother to define "weakly convex in the sense of support functions" if it was just going to be equivalent to convexity? When one has a separate condition that is equivalent to a definition, one usually just proves a theorem stating such-and-such is whatchamacallit if and only this condition is true. One does not create define a second name for the other conditions in this situation. So the very fact someone did define a name suggests it will not be equivalent.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Well, it was me who gave the name to distinguish it from the usual notion of weak convexity (which is usually in the sense of distributions)... I can't find it on any other book, but the last notion is systematically used in Peter Petersen's _Riemannian Geometry_ book (where he did not give a name, but instead explained what it means to say $f''\geq0$ when $f$ is merely continuous).

Comment: Actually , that definition is weak convexity is also not one I've seen before. When I look it up online the first definition I see is midpoint convexity: $f((a + b)/2) \le (f(a) + f(b))/2$ for all $a,b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three notions are equivalent.

The proof that being weakly convex in the support sense is equivalent to being convex is on page 39 of [these notes](http://www.math.toronto.edu/vtk/eschenburg-comparison.pdf). Hope it's helpful for those struggling with Petersen's book (as I am now)!

The proof that being weakly convex in the distribution sense is equivalent to being convex is Theorem 4.1.6 in *The Analysis of Linear Differential Operators I: Distribution Theory and Fourier Analysis* by Lars Hörmander.